# GDB: Initialize memory with fixed value

Tags: debugging, gdb

In my code I have somewhere an uninitialized pointer that seems to get freed. The project is quite large and I cannot find the value. The problem is: once I attach a debugger, memory seems to be initialized with zero causing the pointer to be `NULL` and `free` not causing trouble. Is there a way to initialize the memory when using GDB with something like `0xDEADBEEF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to initialize the memory when using GDB with something like 0xDEADBEEF

Sure, if you know it's address: `(gdb) call memset($addr, 0xCC, $size)` or
 `(gdb) set *(int*)$addr = 0xDEADBEEF`.

The problem is usually that you don't know *where* that uninitialized pointer will be in memory.

One way to find it is with [Memory Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer).

Another way is to figure out whether this pointer is global, on stack, or on heap, where it is *supposed* to be initialized, and set access watchpoint on it with the [awatch](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) command.

P.S. You seem pretty convinced that your problem is "free uninitialized", but the symptoms of "double free" are often similar. I would try [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) before doing anything else.

Comment: There's also valgrind, if you want to avoid recompiling the program.